# C++ Qt QStandardItemModel multiple search clause

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel

I'm kinda having troubles searching for an item in a QStandardItemModel Table. The standard `findItems()` function only searches for one column whereas i need to find an item in the table using 2 columns. Just like a table is searched in Sql using the `WHERE clause1 AND clause2`. But i just can't get this done in Qt.

So far this is what i've got.

Model name - price_model

Columns - Product, Id, Date, Price, Family, Batch

I need to find a row that has a specific product in a specific family. But QStandardItemModel only allows me to search for a specific product only and that returns a list of rows containing the product of all families. 
How can i search for a product belonging only to a given family using QStandardItemModel

This is the code in question.

```
QString product = getProduct( order_id );

QString family = getFamily( order_id );

QList< QStandardItem* > price_item = price_model->findItems(product, Qt::MatchFixedString, 0 );

 if ( !price_item.empty() ) {

      for ( QList< QStandardItem* >::const_iterator it = price_item.begin(); it != price_item.end(); ++ it ) {

       const QStandardItem* index_item = price_model->item( ( *it )->row(), 4 );

        if ( index_item->data().toString() == family ) {
          return;
        }
    }        
} else {
   return;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplement `filterAcceptsRow` virtual member-function.

Comment: Hmm, gotta look into it...

Comment: In your code you look for the family match but then just return? Shouldn't that handle the item?

Comment: No. Searching for family returns all product category that falls in that family. But i need a list of a specific product category belonging to a specific family

Comment: This is really troublesome to get right... Been searching over the internet for days without any good piece of solution...